# Chef: how to clean up old builds of tomcat

Tags: tomcat, chef-infra, multiple-instances

I am writing a cookbook to install multiple tomcat instances of same application on same host. My current pointer will point to latest build.
If I have to deploy for 2 ports, I will have 2 symlinks-
   current_port1 -> build1
   current_port2 -> build2
 How can I write the code to delete all builds older than the latest 2 builds on server?

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat of a tautology but the way you do it is to write the code you described. Get the list of installed versions, sort it based on timestamp or whatever, drop the newest two, and then recursively delete the rest.